# Doctrine 1.2 does not set reference field when loading one-to-one relation

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, one-to-one, relation

I have simple schema with one-to-one relation:

```
Site:
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255) }
User:
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255) }
    site_id: { type: integer }
  relations:
    Site: { foreignType: one }
```

I am overriding Site::save() method (which is called when I edit Site from admin generator), where I need to do smth with User, and User references Site again:

```
echo $this->getUser()->getSite()->getName();
```

When getSite() is called, $this is overwritten by values from database, because Doctrine loads "Site" relation from db and replaces $this according to identity map. Obviously, all changes to object are lost. After some code reading i got that User object does not have _references['Site'] set after getUser(), that's why Doctrine tries to load Site from db. If i prepend

$this->getUser()->setSite($this);

, then everything works as expected and no additional queries are made. Another workaround is to join relations in query:

```
$this->site = Doctrine::getTable('Site')
  ->createQuery('s')
  ->leftJoin('s.User u')
  ->leftJoin('u.Site us')
  ->fetchOne();
```

But is that an intended behaviour? How can I make Doctrine know that $this === $this->getUser()->getSite()? I use symfony 1.4.18 with Doctrine 1.2.4. Thank you.